# Проверка сформированы ли два числа через перестановку цифр

Tags: c++, c, функции, числа, проверка

Функция принимает 2 `int` числа с одинаковым количеством цифр, нужно проверить, сформированы ли они через перестановку цифр, т.е. цифры в них те же, но в другом порядке.
Пример: если передать 1231 и 3211, функция должна возвращать 1.
Долго уже думаю над задачей, не могу придумать ни одного разумного способа, прошу у вас, коллеги, помощи или подсказок.

Comment: Преобразовать числа в строки, отсортировать обе, сравнить.

Comment: Необходимо взять первое число и найти из скольки чисел. После брать каждый символ и смотреть если во втором числе , если да то сумировать переменную , если в конце переменная для суммы будет ровна количеству символов то тру возвращаете. Проще перевести инт в string и там сравнивать как символы

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Заводите массив на 10 элементов из нулей. Идёте циклом по первому числу, откусывая каждый раз последнюю цифру и добавляя единицу соответствующему элементу в массиве. Потом идёте по второму числу, вычитая так же единицу из массива для каждой цифры. Если в конце все элементы массива равны 0, то числа состоят из одних и тех же цифр.